# Given Columns A and B, how do I group values of column B that have the same value in A?

Tags: google-sheets

Here is an example image with an expected result, as you can see Jon and Alice get grouped together as they share the same date (and so do Bob and Carter).

[image: Practical example]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Similar (answered) question from StackOverflow: [JOIN results of VLOOKUP into one string in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58684343/1330560). Pretty sure there is an equivalent on webapps, but this should get you going.